# How to include only sections of Assembly include files

Tags: function, assembly, include, x86, masm

I have created a separate include files for general purpose uses in my assembly programs. (such as string operations / formatted input/etc.)
When i include those files i notice all of the functions get included in the target binary file.

Is there way I can manage to include only the used functions(like using include files in C/C++ library files)?

I'm using MASM and targeting x86.

Comment: MASM doesn't support function-level linking, so there's no simple way of doing this to my knowledge. You could add a bunch of defines that determine which parts of the code to compile, or split your general purpose code into multiple assembly files that you assemble into separate object files.

Comment: In `Makefile`, you could copy each input file to another name and then filter these copies with some regular expression[s] (reading the data on functions used directly from the source eg. with awk or Perl) based on the functions you want to get included this time, and include these regex-filtered copies, and not the complete original ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract separate functions from an object file, the linker needs to know where each one starts and where it ends. It can't reliably tell that from the assembly, so you need to help it.

A common way is to put each function into a separate file and assemble them like that; this way the linker can include or exclude each object file independently. This is the simplest way and works with most assemblers, not just MASM, so I'd recommend trying it.

Another way could be to put each function into a separate segment; the MS linker can exclude unused segments but *only* if they're marked as so-called "COMDAT" (communal data). Unfortunately, MASM does not support setting this attribute.

There have been some work on adding this info to the OBJ file as a post-processing step, but unfortunately the archive with the tool seems to be gone from the Internet:

[Function level linking with MASM](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20040212035208/http://www.launcherasm.com/technical/comdats.html)

Additional links:

[How to achieve "function level linking" with MASM?](http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=9910.0) (includes a tool for semi-automated splitting into several files).

[flat assembler - COMDAT support](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=4706)

[MSDN forums - Comdat](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/09bb0ad3-6415-4384-a9df-3e6720c38189)

[JWASM: 
Support for COFF COMDATs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwasm/forums/forum/927109/topic/4735686/)

The last link mentions "Support for COMDAT is added in jwasm v2.10."